# Determine on iPhone if user has enabled AutoFill Passwords

Tags: swift, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Hyperlink is shown at last for attached image, want to show highlighted option value from device setting section to my app .

How to get current value of AutoFill Passwords in  Passwords & Accounts section of Settings in iOS?

There is any api available for this or have any sample code for the same?

I want to access this setting programmatically Like below,

Ex:- To check notification setting we can use below code

```
let isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications = UIApplication.shared.isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications
```

Just like this I want below setting
[image: Setting Image]

Comment: I searched the document and there seems no such function to check whether user has enable the autofill password in setting or not.

Comment: news ? is it possible to check the value programmatically?